# How to change TLS protocol settings in HttpClient in Ballerina

Tags: ssl, wso2, tls1.2, ballerina, ballerina-http

I want to change TLS protocol settings in a `http:Client` just like in `http:Listener` class. Since they both support TLS configurations, I was able to change TLS configs in a Ballerina server, but was unable to do so in a Ballerina client.

This is the code I wrote for ballerina server. I checked with Wireshark that it uses TLS 1.2

```
listener http:Listener securedEP = new (9090,
    secureSocket = {
        key: {
            certFile: "./serverpubliccert.crt",
            keyFile: "./serverpvtkey.key"
        },
        protocol: {
            name: "TLS",
            versions: ["TLSv1.2"]
        }
    }
);
```

However, when I wrote the same way in a ballerina client, I got **TLS 1.3** requests. (Verified in wireshark)

```
http:Client helloClient = check new ("localhost:9090",
    secureSocket = {
        enable: false,
        protocol: {
            name: "TLS",
            versions: ["TLSv1.2"]
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `enable: false` in the secureSocket config, disables the client certificate validation. Setting it to `true` should work. But in that case, you should configure the server certificate as follows,

```
secureSocket = {
    cert: "server.crt",
    protocol: {
        name: "TLS",
        versions: ["TLSv1.2"]
    }
}
```